# jquery: using "on" instead of "live"

Tags: jquery

Since jquery 10 doesn't support live() I'm using on(). Problem is that on() doesn't detect classes which are added or removed using addClass() and removeClass().

I add the class **menu-accordion-open** but the function **$('.menu a.menu-accordion-open').on()** is never fired and the function **$('.menu a.menu-accordion-closed').on()** is fired instead. The class is added properly. No error in the console.

Code:

```
   $('.menu a.menu-accordion-closed').on( "click", function(e) {
    console.log('111');
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".menu-accordion").stop().animate({left:'0px'},200);
            $('.menu a.header').addClass( "menu-accordion-open" );
            $('.menu a.header').removeClass( "menu-accordion-closed" );
    });
    $('.menu a.menu-accordion-open').on( "click", function(e) {
    console.log('222');
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".menu-accordion").stop().animate({left:'-279px'}, 100);
            $('.menu a.header').removeClass( "menu-accordion-open" );
            $('.menu a.header').addClass( "menu-accordion-closed" );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following instead

```
$('body').on( "click", ".menu a.menu-accordion-closed", function(e) {
   .
   .
   .
});

$('body').on( "click", ".menu a.menu-accordion-open", function(e) {
  .
  .
  .
});
```

You can also replace `body` with the closest parent of `.menu` to gain a tiny pit of performance (almost of negligible significance though)

This is called as event delegation. You can refer to the **Direct and Delegated Events** subtopic mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, but missed context parameter. Read this  [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) concept and below the way how it applied:

```
$(document).on( "click", '.menu a.menu-accordion-closed', function(e) {
console.log('111');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".menu-accordion").stop().animate({left:'0px'},200);
        $('.menu a.header').addClass( "menu-accordion-open" );
        $('.menu a.header').removeClass( "menu-accordion-closed" );
});
$(document).on( "click", '.menu a.menu-accordion-open', function(e) {
console.log('222');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".menu-accordion").stop().animate({left:'-279px'}, 100);
        $('.menu a.header').removeClass( "menu-accordion-open" );
        $('.menu a.header').addClass( "menu-accordion-closed" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu a.menu-accordion-closed', function() {
```

This will help

Find the [DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info